# Adding clickable views dynamically to ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, onclicklistener

I'm a newbie to Android development, so apologies if the answers seem obvious to others...

I want to create a task tracker app for my org, where the set of tasks are usually about the same.  Here's a mockup:
[Project Progress Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcMw7.gif)

The mockup shows generic task names, but the real one will have different task names and more of them.

I need some help sorting out the layout design.  Conceptually, this is pretty straightforward, but the implementation in Android turns out not to be so straightforward...

I thought I should create a "Task Item" class which contains 3 views:  a text view for the task name, a progress bar & another text view for the percentage.  Then I wanted to create an array of these Task Items.

Setting all this up in XML is not so bad, but I need it to be dynamic, as it will not always be the same list.  Also, using XML is kinda brute force, as I would need to have unique code for each item in this activity, rather than looping through the list dynamically.

It seems like I need a ScrollView.  I saw from another post the following statement:

> A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

So I understand that I need to add my list of Task Items to something like a LinearLayout, which is embedded in the ScrollView.  **This I can simply set up in XML, right?**

Then, for each Task Item, I need to:
- create 2 TextViews
- set the text to the task name & percentage, respectively
- set the font, font size, text color, etc.
- set the TextView positions
- create a Progress Bar
- set the Progress Bar position & percentage

None of this is trivial.  So I wonder if it would be easier to set up an XML layout for a single task item & then somehow load() the XML layout.  Hopefully from there I could simply set the text & Progress Bar percentage.  **Would this work, or am I going about this wrong?  Also, how would I set up the XML for this?  Do I add an activity to my project, or just another XML file?**

Finally, I need the task name to be clickable, so I can capture the click & open a new activity showing the subtasks for a task & allowing the user to change the status.  Therefore the task name TextView needs to have an ID.  **Should I make the task names Buttons rather than TextViews?  How can I set the ID dynamically?**  I see that there is a setId(int id) method for Views.  But how do I know what integer to use?  Android reference View.html states:

> View IDs need not be unique throughout the tree, but it is good
>   practice to ensure that they are at least unique within the part of
>   the tree you are searching.

How do I ensure that these IDs are unique?

In the XML file, IDs are not numbers, but rather text, like:

```
android:id="@+id/my_button"
```

And this is referenced in the code like this:

```
Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

**But how do I create & use unique numeric IDs in order to capture click events on these task names?**

### Thanks for any pointers you can give!

New information & questions...

I have the basic functionality working, but a couple things aren't quite right:

1. If you look at my updated mockup, [Updated Project Progress Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLyxs.gif), I want the area highlighted in green to scroll, while the rest stays in place.  However, the heading at the top & the button at the bottom scroll off the screen and won't come back.  Not sure what I did wrong.

My layout xml looks like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/summary"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBG"
tools:ignore="LabelFor"
tools:context="com.myorg.myapp.ProjSummary">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtSumm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/summ"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtProj"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtProj"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/proj"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtSumm"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/edtProj"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtProj"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtSumm"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/txtProj"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSend"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/my_logo"
    android:contentDescription="@string/org_logo"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSend"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorSecondaryDark"
    android:text="@string/send"
    android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imgLogo"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvTaskList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtProj"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgLogo"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

2. My last task item never is displayed.  (i.e. if I have 10 task items, only the first 9 are displayed.)  In my activity class, I have an ArrayList for the summary list of task items:

   ```
   private ArrayList _alSummaries;
   ```

And in my RecyclerView.Adapter class, I have the following method:

```
    @Override
public int getItemCount() { return _alSummaries.size(); }
```

Anywhere else I should look?

### Thanks!

Further update:

1. in my layout I had...

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Rather than wrap_content, it should have been "0dp".  Seems like a bug in Android, actually - if I say wrap_content, that should never cause the view to become larger than the space available to it (as set by the constraints).

2. Problem solved - not a problem with the interface, but with the code that loaded my data into the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I wonder if it would be easier to set up an XML layout for a single task item & then somehow load() the XML layout. Hopefully from there I could simply set the text & Progress Bar percentage.

This is what a Recycler View adapter does. You have an xml layout containing the three simple views: a text, the bar and another text.

Now in your code (in the adapter), you inflate each row and set the text and progress bar individually.

> Should I make the task names Buttons rather than TextViews? How can I set the ID dynamically?

You do not need to do that. You can just assign custom onClick listeners which do what you want in the adapter code.

For a beginner, the setup is definitely not trivial, but once you get the hang of it, you will find it to be a very valuable tool.

Look here for the official tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your response...
"This is what a Recycler View adapter does. You have an xml layout containing the three simple views: a text, the bar and another text."
I never guessed a RecyclerView would support a scrollable list. I looked at the official tutorial, but it was pretty sparse & confusing.  Better as a reference for those who already learned this stuff. Not for beginners. The following YouTube Videos were more helpful:
_Let's Build a RecyclerView App | Beginner Android Development Tutorial_
Still not working quite right, though.  More on that to follow...